# Angular lazy loading routing always goes to wildcard module

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I am working on a new Angular application that has multiple modules. I am still struggling to get my routing correct. In the following (simplified) example, I want to lazy load the `StoreModule`. If no url is given, I want my application to redirect to `/store`. If an invalid URL is given, I want my `NotFoundComponent` to be shown. In my current configuration however, the `NotFoundComponent` is always shown, regardless of the URL. Do you guys see what I am doing wrong?

This is my `app.module.ts` file, I would expect it to only use the `RouterModule` provided in `NotFoundModule` if no URL matches can be made.

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AuthModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'store', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'store', loadChildren: 'app/store/store.module#StoreModule'},
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
    ]),
    LoginModule,
    NotfoundModule,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

This is my `StoreModule`. If I comment out the `NotFoundModule` in my `app.module.ts` module this all works as expected.

**store.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AuthModule,
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'dashboard' },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    ]),
  ],
  declarations: [StoreTemplateComponent, DashboardComponent]
})
export class StoreModule { }
```

**notfound.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: '**',
        component: NotfoundComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ NotfoundComponent ],
})
export class NotfoundModule { }
```

Comment: That didn't do the trick unfortunately (is it even relevant in a wildcard route?)

Answer (score 0):

Your router setting looks OK. One thing to look at is
you have AuthGuard in 'dashboard' which must redirect 
and that redirecting URL must be wrong, 
so you are redirected to NotFoundComponent.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score -1):

*If no url is given, I want my application to redirect to /store. If an invalid URL is given, I want my NotFoundComponent to be shown.*

If this is the requirement then you need to remove **notfound.module.ts** . Or you need to load it lazily as in the present set up you are not loading it in your routes and by adding it in app modules it loads up front and treats all the routes as wild card.

you can just have a **NotfoundComponent** and add it to your existing routes.

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'store', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'store', loadChildren: 'app/store/store.module#StoreModule'},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: '**', component: NotfoundComponent } // this should work
]),
```